How to get ESLint to show a warning for deprecated rules?
ESLint recently deprecated a bunch of rules (see here).
My project is using some of those rules, and I am currently on ESLint version 8.57.0.
However when I run ESLint using npm run lint, I do not get any warning output saying the rules are deprecated. How can I get ESLint to notify me about deprecated rules, so I can update/migrate them?
package.json:
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",


TLDR; For a project using ESLint v8 and .eslintrc.* (legacy) configuration files, try the following command to discover the deprecated(and even removed) rules in the configuration:
npx @rightcapital/lint-eslint-config-rules


The process of rule deprecation usually involves one of the following, or sequentially one after the other:

A rule exists, but it has metadata that says:
a. it is deprecated
b. it is replaced by another rule(s)

A rule no longer exists. (It was there in the past, but has now been removed)


For the first scenario, the deprecation information is available in the rule's metadata, but ESLint does not provide a direct way to find these deprecated rules. However, it is possible to discover the deprecated rules by:

Determining the rules used in the project
Finding the metadata of each rule for deprecation information

For the second scenario, ESLint shows an error message when a non-existent rule is enabled. If the rule is disabled, ESLint does not generate any error message. We still have to manually identify the removed rules to clean up the ESLint configuration. We need to:

Determining the rules used in the project
Resolve all the rules known to ESLint
Compare the resolved rules with the rules used

The steps above are not straightforward. To simplify the process, the script @rightcapital/lint-eslint-config-rules was created to perform these steps and display the deprecated and removed rules in the ESLint configuration.
